# Capture rendered markup between two arbitrary points in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I'd like to be able to do the following in a razor page:

```
<div> some markup
    @using(var myMarkupCapturer = Html.CaptureHtml())
    {
         <div>this markup will be captured</div>
    }
</div>
```

Any suggestions? I was thinking about substituting the TextWriter of my ViewContext (`ViewContext.Writer`) for a specialized version that can be intercepted. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does it have to happen on the server side? Why not render the page and use client side JavaScript to get the markup and output it into the target div?

Comment: @Lost_Cause Yes... It's part of a larger project concerned with the automatic creation of knockout.js templates. Given the tumbleweed around this question, I'll post my solution here once I've put all the pieces together.